# Getting the address which caused the error

Tags: c++, assembly

Im not really sure how to phrase it on google.I continuously get irrelevant results so i decided to ask here instead.
I am wondering if its possible to get the Address/Function which caused the exception error.I think that i should get the EIP and find what address last set it ? but im not sure how to go about doing so(finding what address last set it if my thoughts were right).
Any help / advice would be appreciated

Comment: I plan for it to be a large dll , and i need to log it for easier fixing

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using an IDE that has a debugger, like Visual Studio, then you can set breakpoints and start debugging your project.

Maybe this link can help you? 
http://kipirvine.com/asm/debug/vstudio2010/